# presto create table from another table with double quotes with comma separated

Tags: hive, presto, trino, presto-jdbc

How to create table in **presto** from a select query that has comma-separated values inside the column itself.
e.g 
select statement has values look like

| Column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | abc,xyz |

below is the create  statement for table

> CREATE TABLE resultTable
> WITH (format = 'TEXTFILE',textfile_field_separator = ',')
> AS
> select Column1 ,column2 column3  from sourceTable

but this ends up with missing placing fields which have comma separated values

Comment: What is the desired result? How the resulting table should look?

Comment: It should be same as source table mentioned in question

Comment: You want to split `abc,xyz` into separate rows?

Comment: No it should be same as source column. Means failed value is comma separated

Comment: So the `resultTable` should be the same as the source one?

Comment: Yes correct , source table is in orc and goal is to export(create another table with query logic) data with CSV format

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251336/discussion-between-user2928137-and-guru-stron).